# How to use JFactory::getDBO() in public?

Tags: joomla, joomla-dbo

I have created new **php** file in component.  I want to get connection to **Joomla** database but connection unknown.  Error message is the following:

```
Fatal error: Class 'JFactory' not found in D:\www\Joomla1.5\components\com_hello\views\hello\tmpl\index.php on line 13
```

How do I use  `JFactory::getDBO()` in public ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to get a database object in your tmpl? DB objects should only be used in either your controller or model, never in your view or tmpl. Tmpl should contain very little logic code and mostly HTML.

The idea is to get your information needed by calling a function in your model. You then pass this data by reference to your tmpl where you echo it out.

**[EDIT]**

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery('INSERT INTO #__table (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)');
$result = $db->query();
if ($result === null) {
  JError::raiseWarning(100, $db->getErrorMsg());
}
```

Comment: so can you give me simple code insert data to database in joomla ? in component

Answer (score 0):

Hi in my case `$result === null` not worked, but !$result - worked good

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery('INSERT INTO #__table (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)');
$result = $db->query();
if (!$result) {
  JError::raiseWarning(100, $db->getErrorMsg());
}
```